# Can't properly delete rows from a dynamically generated table using a button

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have the following code which is supposed to generate rows in a table where each row has its own content and delete button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>table</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="inputText">
        <button onclick = "addRow()">Add text</button>

        <table id = "table">
        </table>
        <script>
            function addRow(){

                var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
                var col1 = document.createElement("td");
                var col2 = document.createElement("td");
                newRow.appendChild(col1);
                newRow.appendChild(col2);

                var button = document.createElement("button");
                button.innerHTML = "delete";

                button.onclick = function () {
                    var index = this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
                    document.getElementById("table").deleteRow(index);
                }
                col1.appendChild(button);


                var enteredText = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
                col2.innerHTML = enteredText;

                document.getElementById("table").appendChild(newRow);

            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that no matter which delete button I press, it deletes the last row. 
I tried using `console.log(this.parentNode.parentNode)` to see if it returns the right `<tr>` object, and it indeed does. But for some reason, the attribute `rowIndex` is -1 no matter what button is pressed; hence only the last row is deleted. Does it mean that each dynamically generated `<tr>` doesn't know its row index?

Comment: What's your browser? it works with me on Firefox, but not on Chrome !!

Comment: I've tried it both on Chrome and Safari (both for Mac), and it works in none of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`HTMLTableElement.insertRow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow) function instead.

```
var newRow = document.getElementById("table").insertRow();
// newRow.rowIndex will return you the proper index
```

**[Here is a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/moeetwj3/)**

**Update**

It was a bug in the Webkit layout engine, (that moved to the forked Blink engine as well). This is why it works well in Firefox but not in *earlier versions of Chrome* (Blink) or Safari (Webkit).

The bug report is [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=495884), it's fixed now.

Comment: No 'have to' about it. This would be one solution.

Comment: @Xotic750 Yes, The 'have to' was part of my old answer (that I forgot to remove as well). At first, I thought there's something wrong with the object referenced by `parentNode`. But I realized that the OP code is ok but for some reason it doesn't work on Chrome ("and Safari"), and works well on FireFox !!

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous way to achieve what you require. Here is another such example that is based on the code that you posted. Hopefully it will give you some further ideas.

```js
(function() {
  // create references to static elements, no need to search for them each time
  var inputText = document.getElementById("inputText"),
      butAdd = document.getElementById("butAdd"),
      table = document.getElementById("table");

  // a generic function for finding the first parent node, starting at the given node and
  // of a given tag type. Retuns document if not found.
  function findParent(startNode, tagName) {
    var currentNode,
        searchTag;

    // check we were provided with a node otherwise set the return to document
    if (startNode && startNode.nodeType) {
      currentNode = startNode;
    } else {
      currentNode = document;
    }

    // check we were provided with a string to compare against the tagName of the nodes
    if (typeof tagName === 'string') {
      searchTag = tagName.toLowerCase();
    } else {
      currentNode = document;
    }

    // Keep searching until we find a parent with a mathing tagName or until we get to document
    while (currentNode !== document && currentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() !== searchTag) {
      currentNode = currentNode.parentNode;
    }

    // return the match or document
    return currentNode;
  }

  // for deleting the current row in which delete was clicked
  function deleteRow(e) {
    // find the parent with the matching tagName
    var parentTr = findParent(e.target, 'tr');

    // did we find it?
    if (parentTr !== document) {
      // remove it
      parentTr.parentNode.removeChild(parentTr);
    }
  }

  // for adding a row to the end of the table
  function addRow() {
    // create the required elements
    var newRow = document.createElement("tr"),
        col1 = document.createElement("td"),
        col2 = document.createElement("td"),
        button = document.createElement("button");

    // add some text to the new button
    button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("delete"));
    // add a click event listener to the delete button
    button.addEventListener('click', deleteRow, false);

    // append all the required elements
    col1.appendChild(button);
    col2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputText.value));
    newRow.appendChild(col1);
    newRow.appendChild(col2);

    // finally append all the elements to the document
    table.appendChild(newRow);
  }

  // add click event listener to the static Add text button
  butAdd.addEventListener('click', addRow, false);
}());
```

```html
<input id="inputText">
<button id="butAdd">Add text</button>
<table id="table"></table>
```