# javascript dyanmic table add / delete row

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a form for creating a list for image deployment.

[image: Image example of my table]

I am able to create a dynamic table on form load and also collect the data for each value, but can seem to get the Add and Delete working.
My Question:

What must I do(or change) in my code to get the ADD and Delete options working and to export the table data in CSV format.

Please could someone help and/or guide me as I am getting so lost and really would like a working example .. there is so much on the net it's over-whelming
Newest place I visited is Mozilla DOM help pages what's confusing is how to load your own variables into the table

For reference I used stackoverflow and plenty google and finally [this site](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-add-remove-rows-in-html-table-using-javascript/)

Here is my code:

```
<div id="metric_results">
Enter Target Name:
<input type="text" name="textbox1" id="textbox1" VALUE="win2k8"/> 
<br>
<input type="button" id="create" value="Click here" onclick="Javascript:addTable()">
<input type="button" id="create" value="Add Row" onclick="Javascript:addRow()">
<input type="button" id="create" value="Delete Row" onclick="Javascript:deleteRow()">

</div>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
window.onload =addTable;//loads table on window loading
function addTable() {
var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("metric_results")
var table = document.createElement('TABLE')
var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY')
var imageName = textbox1.value
table.border = '1'
table.appendChild(tableBody);

var heading = new Array();
heading[0] = "imageName"
heading[1] = "acceptAllEula"
heading[2] = "noSSLverify"
heading[3] = "noVerification"
heading[4] = "TargetImagelocation"
heading[5] = "Username"
heading[6] = "Password"
heading[7] = "Target IP"

var imageInfo = new Array()
imageInfo[0] = new Array(imageName, "acceptAllEula", "noSSLverify", "noVerification", "testLocation", "user", "pass", "192.168.1.151")
imageInfo[1] = new Array("win2008", "acceptAllEula", "noSSLverify", "noVerification", "testLocation", "user", "pass", "192.168.1.151")



//TABLE COLUMNS
var tr = document.createElement('TR');
tableBody.appendChild(tr);
for (i = 0; i < heading.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement('TH')
    th.width = '75';
    th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(heading[i]));
    tr.appendChild(th);
}

//TABLE ROWS
for (i = 0; i < imageInfo.length; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    for (j = 0; j < imageInfo[i].length; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement('TD')
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(imageInfo[i][j]));
        tr.appendChild(td)
    }
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);
}  
myTableDiv.appendChild(table)
}

function addRow() {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;



        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "checkbox";
        element1.name="chkbox[]";
        cell1.appendChild(element1);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.type = "text";
        element2.name = "txtbox[]";
        cell3.appendChild(element2);

    }

function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }


        }
        function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }


        }
        }catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }


</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: What is it that your code doesn't do exactly? Do you see any errors in the console? I personally would not use in-line Javascript and would separate CSS, HTML and Javascript into their own files, also see  [unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). I generally only use libraries if they are actually necessary, like for specific (older) browser support, but it depends on numerous things. HTML `id`s should also be unique.

Comment: @Xotic750 - I'm not sure what's not clear to you? Specifically though , as mentioned the ADD and DELETE row functions don't work :-(

Comment: Specifically, does Add or Delete fire their listeners on click, do the handlers execute, are there any visible errors in the console, what is the expected behaviour when compared to the actual behaviour? And I don't mean "it doesn't work".

Comment: A link to jsfiddle, will help us a lot here...

Comment: As mentioned the ADD and DELETE row functions don't work.All I have been trying to do for two weeks is build a table from the simple form I created using HTML and finally export the table to csv. I've google docs for what I want and many survey sites. I have a set of questions in a form and want users to be able to answer the questions then click an ADD button which will load their answers into a Row in a table. They need to be able to remove selected ROWS too. A submit button will SUBMITH the final table values into a CSV file.

Comment: @Jeremy ok will make a jsfiddle ..thanks for the tip

Comment: An example from another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30553848/cant-properly-delete-rows-from-a-dynamically-generated-table-using-a-button/30555483#30555483

Comment: @Xotic750 .. Wow ok .. that's a little OTT(over the top) for me.. I just put this all in a basic HTML form hopefully fit for function and purpose eventually, no frills belles and whistles nor fame and glory or money, so no need for CSS or anything fancy

Comment: aaargh .. I have it in a jsfiddle but now nothing's working .. please stand by for update

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dina0000/egtu5kay/1/    I swear this does work if all is put in a plain html file. .. please see pic in original post .. is it fiddle ?

Comment: Set it to "No wrap in- body" And what is `tableID` in `var table = document.getElementById(tableID);`? The console says `Uncaught ReferenceError: tableID is not defined`

Comment: @Xotic750 .that's where I was battling too :-( , firstly to give the table an ID (I thought since it's created it gets an auto assigned name ? and if I leave (tableID) out like this () that doesn't work either. BTW I saw your fiddle ..WOW ..cool.. but raises plenty questions like how to I get my whole array into column and rows and then when I add a ROW how can I add the new variables to each column. I had just today managed to get my head around the inner outer for loops and their counters.

Comment: Well, your not setting an `id` on your `table` and [`document.getelementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) requires one.

Comment: @Xotic750 ..Thanks a million for the "No wrap in- body" tip ..you ROCK!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not setting any `id` to the table you're creating `onload` - so when you later come to call `getElementById()` inside `addRow` it cannot be found (and you're using a variable which does not exist - `tableID`!)

My suggestion is to take an `id` as a parameter to `addTable`, and set that as the `id` of the dynamically generated table:

```
function addTable(id) {
  var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("metric_results")
  var table = document.createElement('TABLE')
  table.id = id;
  ....
```

`onload`, pass somethig sensible - `default` perhaps:

```
window.onload = function(){
    addTable("default");
}
```

And either pass this in when adding a row, or use the default provided above:

```
function addRow() {
  var table = document.getElementById("default");
  ....
```

or

```
function addRow(id) {
  var table = document.getElementById(id);
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/egtu5kay/5/

Left as an exercise for you: Correctly formatting the new row as you wish.